# meteor :Cannot find module '../modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor'

Tags: meteor

```
G:\projects\todos>meteor
[[[[[ ~\G\projects\todos ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.  
=> Started MongoDB.    
=> Errors prevented startup:
While loading plugin `compileTemplatesBatch` from package `templating`:  
module.js:338:15: Cannot find module '../modules/es6.object.get-own-  property-descriptor'
.....  
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I've followed the tutorial to create  a new app on todo, but the app can not "meteor".
How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, update meteor to the latest version by running `meteor update` in the project folder. There is a known issue with long pathnames in windows and meteor 1.3 that was resolved in 1.3.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is indeed resolved if you're on a version of meteor < 1.3.1 AND you're running Windows. I just ran into the same issue myself and performed the update suggested by michmach.